# Duplicate files in Canopy's split window

Tags: enthought

I cannot figure out how to open the same file in two different panes of the editor when I have split it. I right click to create a new pane, but then dragging a file that is open in the first pane only moves the file. Is it possible to view the same file in multiple panes?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it by splitting. Do it by opening a new Editor window (File menu).